# The meal with wine came to $20 each. (What's the meaning of th sentence?)

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The meal with wine came to $20 each.

1. meal $20 and wine $20
2. meal+wine $20 for each person

My dictionary explains the meaning as 2.

Is there any chance to interpret as 1?

Comment: In a word, no. You would have to say something like "The meal cost $20, with another twenty for the wine."

Comment: On the other hand I might say "the meal *and* wine came to $20 each" and it would be ambiguous whether I was saying that there were multiple people, each paying $20 for (meal + wine), for a total of $20xNumberOfPeople or if (meal) cost $20 and (wine) cost $20 totalling $40 regardless of the number of people. Even if you knew there were multiple people paying, you couldn't disambiguate them without more context.

Comment: The "alternative" meaning is very unlikely in the real world (we normally care about *how much **per person***, not how much for the food and how much separately for the wine). But to *convey* that less-common meaning, all you really have to do is move ***each*** to a less-common position: *The meal and the wine **each came to** $20* (and definitely connect the two subjects using ***and***, not ***with***).